# 2d board raw_put string out_ put board coordinates

Tags: python

In python what I am trying to do is to have a function `def players_move` that takes a raw_input string of len 5 such as `b1,i5` making checks that the move is legal, then a new function called `cords()` that takes the string and outputs the coordinates to be updated on the 2d board.

Below is what i have for turning the string into coordinates. It works if i ask it to return `b[2],i[5]` but i cant get it to take the string then output the x and y coordinates with out errors or it just returning the string and not the coordinates.

```
def cords ():
    move=raw_input('enter starting pos and end pos')        

    a=[[0,0],[1,0],[2,0],[3,0],[4,0],[5,0],[6,0],[7,0],[8,0]]
    b=[[0,1],[1,1],[2,1],[3,1],[4,1],[5,1],[6,1],[7,1],[8,1]]
    c=[[0,2],[1,2],[2,2],[3,2],[4,2],[5,2],[6,2],[7,2],[8,2]]
    d=[[0,3],[1,3],[2,3],[3,3],[4,3],[5,3],[6,3],[7,3],[8,3]]
    e=[[0,4],[1,3],[2,4],[3,4],[4,4],[5,4],[6,4],[7,4],[8,4]]
    f=[[0,5],[1,3],[2,5],[3,5],[4,5],[5,5],[6,5],[7,5],[8,5]]
    g=[[0,6],[1,3],[2,6],[3,6],[4,6],[5,6],[6,6],[7,6],[8,6]]
    h=[[0,7],[1,3],[2,7],[3,7],[4,7],[5,7],[6,7],[7,7],[8,7]]
    i=[[0,8],[1,3],[2,8],[3,8],[4,8],[5,8],[6,8],[7,8],[8,8]]
    xx = move[0], int(move[1])
    #yy = move[3], int(move[4])
    xxx = xx[0],[xx[1]]
    #yyy= yy[3],[yy[4]]
    return xxx#,yyy
```

I have included the raw_input inside the function to have it working without the other parts it is meant to output the coordinates but it is returning ('b'[1]),'i'[5] instead of [1,1],[[3,8]or even better would be for it to out put [1][1],[3][8] if given b1,i5 it has an error if try and return both x and y it doesn't work right with just x but it has no errors Can anyone help?

Then I am going to need to import the returned values and update the board inside a update_board function.

Comment: this function will result in an error ... please post a short self contained code example that demonstrates the problem...http://sscce.org

Comment: What i have been trying is lets call the name of the user input string what is being imported is called move 
I have tryed 
x_cord = move[0] [move[1]] 
Y_cord = move[3][move[4]]
but it returns the number as a sting such as b['1'],i['5'] so I tryed 
x_cord = move[0] int(move[1])
but this makes it so it == to b1,i5 and not b[1],i[5] so it can return the cords

Comment: what I am wanting the code to do is take in say b2,i5 and returns [2,1],[5,8] the x is the starting pos and y is the place the peice is moved to i will have to split [b,2] to be [2][1] for updating the board same for [5,8] i was going to do this in the move funtion once I had turned the user input into the indexs

Comment: @esaelPsnoroMoN: please read http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147100/trogdor-ate-my-homework-tag

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
def get_move(move)  : 
    d = {}
    d['a']=[[0,0],[1,0],[2,0],[3,0],[4,0],[5,0],[6,0],[7,0],[8,0]]
    d['b']=[[0,1],[1,1],[2,1],[3,1],[4,1],[5,1],[6,1],[7,1],[8,1]]
    d['c']=[[0,2],[1,2],[2,2],[3,2],[4,2],[5,2],[6,2],[7,2],[8,2]]
    #made example smaller

    def get_parts(part):
         parts = re.split("([a-zA-Z]+)",part)
     _,ltr,idx =parts
         try:
              return d[ltr.lower()][int(idx)]
         except KeyError:
              raise Exception("Letter {0} Does Not Exist".format(ltr))
         except IndexErrorError:
              raise Exception("Letter {0} Does Not Have Index {1}".format(ltr,idx))
    start,end = move.split(",")

    return get_parts(start),get_parts(end)
print  get_move(raw_input('enter starting pos and end pos'))
```

Result

```
enter starting pos and end posa3,c4
([3, 0], [4, 2])
```

edited to allow caseInsensitive

Comment: Thankyou it works :) I forgot to ask for it to not care if it is lower or upcase such as B1,i5 or B1,D3 if i double the amount of lines such as
d['a']=[[0,0],[1,0],[2,0],[3,0],[4,0],[5,0],[6,0],[7,0],[8,0]]
d['A']=[[0,0],[1,0],[2,0],[3,0],[4,0],[5,0],[6,0],[7,0],[8,0]]
is thre an easyer way to make it not matter on case than adding new lines for lower and uper cases